# instantiate all items in view pager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity with a view pager and three pages to display. When ever the activity loads, only the first two pages are instantiated i.e instantiateitem in the pageradapter class is called only for position 0 and 1. Is there a way to instantiate all the three pages?

Comment: Do you have getCount() method returning 3?

Comment: yes, i have a getCount() method returning 3. The third pages gets instantiated only when i try to view the 2nd page, but by default only the first two are instantiated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try [setOffScreenPageLimit(2)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29). By default only one page to the left and to the right are instantiated. By setting to 2 it should instantiate your 3 pages.

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. I will try that and will let you know how it works.