# FragmentPagerAdapter opens a different fragment automatically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have **`Fragment`** connected with **`FragmentPagerAdapter`**, with code

```
public class LeaveAdapterApproval extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private static final String TAG = LeaveAdapterApproval.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 4;

    public LeaveAdapterApproval(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToAll");
                return new LeaveFragmentToAll();
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, "LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToPending");
                return new LeaveFragmentToPending();
            case 2:
                Log.d(TAG, "LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToApproved");
                return new LeaveFragmentToApproved();
            case 3:
                Log.d(TAG, "LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToDenied");
                return new LeaveFragmentToDenied();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "All";
            case 1:
                return "Pending";
            case 2:
                return "Approved";
            case 3:
                return "Denied";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and results in Logcat

> ```
> 09-22 15:45:21.259 27234-27234/dan.taaku D/LeaveAdapterApproval: LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToPending
> 09-22 15:45:21.259 27234-27234/dan.taaku D/LeaveAdapterApproval: LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToAll
> 09-22 15:45:21.259 27234-27234/dan.taaku D/LeaveAdapterApproval: LOG : CURRENT FRAGMENT LeaveFragmentToApproved
> ```

We can see from the **`Logcat`** results that **`Fragment`** loads three **`Fragments`** at once, I set when the `Fragment` is opened Automatic to `LeaveFragmentToPending` in `LeaveClassApproval`

```
public class LeaveClassApproval extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = LeaveClassApproval.class.getSimpleName();

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    public LeaveClassApproval() {
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hr_employee_leave_class, container, false);

        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new LeaveAdapterApproval(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true); // I set it here

        return view;
    }
}
```

But why `LeaveClassApproval` open `LeaveFragmentToAll` and `LeaveFragmentToApproved`, should not it be opening `LeaveFragmentToPending` instead. Is this a fault or is it a `Fragment` function?

I searched through [Google](https://google.com) but did not find an answer

So how to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046484/instantiate-all-items-in-view-pager-android check this link it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your problem is the default functionallity from the ViewPager itself. It has a variable called offscreenPageLimit, where the default value is 1. Means it'll always load one page to the left and one to the right. And you won't be able to set it to zero, because the source code of android behind it looks like this:,

```
private static final int DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES = 1;

public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
```

If you realy want to get rid of this behaviour one thing you could do is building your own Pager class based on the android source code and simply try to cut out this functionallity.

Comment: you didn't added this. It's just how the android class behaves in the background and the method i postet was from the original android source code. You can find it in the ViewPager.class where you are passing the adapter to.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it's helpful but it seems like if I make my own code it's risky not being compitable

Comment: yes, you'll have to maintain compatability yourself then. I think you should just go with the default behaviour, it won't hurt you. And it probably will also results in a smoother user experience when it loads one page to each side.

Comment: If the default can not be replaced, the application may be slow, because I fill the 4 fragments by reloading the data from the server

Comment: Why reload? The `ViewPager` keeps the fragments in memory if they don't explode it.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `ViewPager` opens the current `Fragment` and its two neighboring ones (that is, the one before and the one after in the data). If you want to change the default behavior use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int numberOfFragmentsToBePreloadedOnEachSideOfTheCurrentFragment)`. Notice, however, that the `ViewPager` will always load at least its two neighbors.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getOffscreenPageLimit()):

> int getOffscreenPageLimit ()
>
> Returns the number of pages that will be retained to either side of
>   the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Defaults to
>   1.

Comment: So ViewPagerAdapter if it will still open 2 fragments at once (adjacent)?

Comment: Yes, with the default `ViewPager` nothing less than 2.

Comment: Can I set it up to 1 ?

Comment: Yes, of course. It will load the current `Fragment`, the next `Fragment` and (if available in the data) the previous `Fragment` - if you start your `ViewPager` at position 0 of your data, it will load 2 `Fragment`s.